# loading another page in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I need to load another page in another website in my jsp page I searched a lot but the only thing that I could find was the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#test").empty();

    $("#test").load('https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=TS7QU6W-   H43b8gelg4HwCA&gws_rd=ssl');

});
```

and here is the jfiddle :
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Wtb/)

but as you can see it is not working. I am wondering if it is possible to do that and if yes how? I appreciate any help

Comment: What about an `iframe`?

Comment: Same Origin Policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy